# Do I need a UK transit visa for traveling from Switzerland to India via London

Tags: visas, uk, transit, indian-citizens

I want to travel to India from Switzerland via London, so do I need a transit visa for UK ?
My onward flight from London is from same terminal within 3 hours.
I am an Indian National having a residence permit B issued by Switzerland. I read that having **"a common format residence permit issued by an European Economic Area (EEA) country or Switzerland"** are exempted from transit visa.

But I am not sure if my residence permit is a common format resident permit and falls in this category. Kindly advise if someone know about this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The common format residence permit in Switzerland is credit card-sized and has CHE and the biometric symbol in the top left corner.

Currently, the following two styles are both valid until the validity indicated on the card.

New style (white base, with a map of Europe and stars on the front): https://www.sem.admin.ch/dam/sem/fr/data/aufenthalt/infoflyer-aa19.pdf.download.pdf/infoflyer-aa19-f.pdf

Old style (pink-blue-pink with a bull and five stars on the front) : https://www.sem.admin.ch/dam/sem/en/data/aufenthalt/flyer-biometr-ausl-ausweis-e.pdf.download.pdf/flyer-biometr-ausl-ausweis-e.pdf

If your permit is being renewed or you are still waiting for it, you may inquire with your cantonal or communal authority to see if a return visa of category D can be issued (which also suffice for transiting UK).

Comment: Thankyou very much for the information. Its really helpful. I have the old style residence permit (pink-blue-pink with a bull and five stars on the front), which means my permit falls in the common format residence permit category and I don't need a transit visa. Thankyou very much.